# Key in dict.keys() not recognized for appending values

Tags: python, dictionary, append, key

I want to append values to my dictionary, when they are present in my file under a certain key. If the key already exists in the dictionary. Otherwise I want to create the key with it's value. E.g.:

```
f=open('Fruits.txt','r')
for line in f:
    field=line.split('\t')
    fruits={}
    if 'Gala' in field[4] and 'Apples' in fruits.keys():
        print 'Cider'
        fruits['Apples'].append('Gala')
    elif 'Gala' in field[4]:
        fruits['Apples']='Gala'
        print fruits.keys()

f.close
```

When I run this script. I don't get any error message, but the 'Cider' is not printed, indicating that the 'Apples' key is not recognized to be in the fruits dictionary. In the meantime the print fruits.keys() does for each line print:

['Apples']

However, when I remove (all) the indentation before the print fruits.keys(), it prints:

[]

Do you know why the the 'Apples' key is being forgotten and/or not recognized?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I see your first (and perhaps only) issue is creating a new dictionary for every iterable in f. I would move that line outside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your example:

```
for line in f:
    field=line.split('\t')
    fruits={}
```

You should initialize the `fruits` dictionary before the loop. Otherwise you will get a new dictionary for every line.

---

`fruits['Apples'].append('Gala')`

On the very first iteration this is guaranteed to raise `KeyError`. Your dictionary is empty but you assume it already has `Apples` as key and an empty list as a value. You should verify that before trying to `append`, or better yet, use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which will save you the hustle.

---

`f.close`

`close` is a function, so this line should be `f.close()`.

---

To sum it up:

```
from collections import defaultdict

f = open('Fruits.txt','r')
fruits = defaultdict(list)
for line in f:
    field=line.split('\t')

    if 'Gala' in field[4] and 'Apples' in fruits.keys():
        print 'Cider'
        fruits['Apples'].append('Gala')
    elif 'Gala' in field[4]:
        fruits['Apples']='Gala'  # This line will change the value to a string
                                 # so you won't be able to "append" to it anymore. 
                                 # I'm not sure what you tried to do here.
        print fruits.keys()

f.close()
```

Or even better, use [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to handle the openning and closing of the file for you:

```
from collections import defaultdict

fruits = defaultdict(list)
with open('Fruits.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
         field = line.split('\t')

         if 'Gala' in field[4] and 'Apples' in fruits.keys():
             print 'Cider'
             fruits['Apples'].append('Gala')
         elif 'Gala' in field[4]:
             fruits['Apples'] = 'Gala'
             print fruits.keys()
```

Comment: A minor improvement: `in` on a dict will always search the keys, so `'Apples' in fruits.keys()` could just be `'Apples' in fruits`.

Answer (score 0):

Your queston needs to clear where do you come with key and values ?!
Below is example, but you should choose the key and value based on your problem:

Try this:

```
f=open('Fruits.txt','r')
fruits= defaultdict(list)
for line in f:
    field=line.split('\t')
    fruits['Apples'].append('Gala') 
f.close
```